# How to print b5 on a4 paper?

Tags: adobe-indesign, crop

I have a b5 file on indesign and I am planning to print it on a4. 
Since my designs don't touch the edge of the page I don't need a bleed, I just need to know where to crop when it prints.

I am wondering how I go about doing this when the surroundings of my design is all white space. Do I just set up printer crop marks specific to b5 page size?

Attached are images to help understand my problem and my current settings. [[image: pic]]

[image: setup]

[image: settings]

Comment: If you’re going to print on A4 paper and then cut off the excess to leave you with B5-sized paper, then yes—just add crop marks and cut accordingly. Are your characters supposed to look like that, though? It’s barely legible (is the seventh one a 亏?) and looks quite… odd.

Comment: Just a tiny detail, since you put in a nice effort to post your first question here (welcome): normally paper/page sizes are given with capital letters for the series (as you can see in your own second screen shot), so A4 and B5 are more common; I believe even more correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I just set up printer crop marks specific to b5 page size?

Yes.

In order to see the crop marks for a B5 size page, you'd have to print to a larger size paper to see them anyway.